# Is there a version of the boolean satisfiability problem that has NC complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, satisfiability

Boolean satisfiability problem (SAT) is NP-complete by Cook–Levin theorem. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem))

Horn-satisfiability – given a set of Horn clauses, is there a variable assignment which satisfies them? This is P's version of the boolean satisfiability problem. It is also P-complete. P-complete problems lie outside NC and so cannot be effectively parallelized. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete))

Is there a version of the boolean satisfiability problem that has NC complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allender, Bauland, Immerman, Schnoor and Vollmer showed in their paper [The Complexity of Satisfiability Problems:
Refining Schaefer’s Theorem](https://people.cs.rutgers.edu/%7Eallender/papers/csp.pdf) that every Boolean constraint satisfaction problem with a finite number of allowed constraints is either in $\mathsf{coNLOGTIME}$ or it is complete for one of the following classes: $\mathsf{NP}, \mathsf{P}, \mathsf{\oplus L}, \mathsf{NL}, \mathsf{L}$ (with respect to $\mathsf{AC^0}$ reductions).

Comment: Do I understand correctly: There is procedure/rules to limit the language of the Boolean constraint satisfaction problem to make it solvable in a time complexity from the listed classes. Then if I can reduce my original problem to SAT ( class) then I can expect to get a solution in $O(n\log n)$ time?

Comment: SAT doesn't belong to coNLOGTIME. coNLOGTIME has nothing to do with $O(n\log n)$ time. I suggest taking a look at the paper, consulting texts on complexity theory as needed.

Comment: I will read the paper even if it looks complicated to me. My original question was about limiting SAT to find a variable assignment that satisfies the formula in a time complexity strictly less than P. For example NC or (log). Can you please suggest if such a class exists?

Comment: Yes, for example if you don't allow negative literals.